# Sorting with overloaded operators on a pointer array

Tags: c++, pointers, overloading

So, to summarize, I have an array of pointers pointing to objects of class "bookType" whose operators have been overloaded and I am trying to use the selection Sort to sort them by quantity in descending order (ie 10 to 1), yet the order is seemingly random after running this code.

Selection Sort

```
void selectionSort(bookType *arr[BOOKS], int n){
    bookType *temp;
    int i, j, minIndex;    
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        minIndex = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
              if (arr[j] > arr[minIndex])
                    minIndex = j;
        if (minIndex != i) {
              temp = arr[i];
              arr[i] = arr[minIndex];
              arr[minIndex] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

bookType prototype:

```
class bookType{
    public:
        bookType();
        string getTitle() const;
        string getAuthor() const;
        string getPublisher() const;
        string getDateAdded() const;
        string getISBN() const;
        int getQty() const;
        double getWholesale() const;
        double getRetail() const;
        static int getBookCount();

        void setTitle(string title);
        void setISBN(string ISBN);
        void setDateAdded(string date);
        void setAuthor(string author);
        void setPublisher(string publisher);
        void setQty(int qty);
        void setWholesale(double wholesale);
        void setRetail(double retail);
        static void setBookCount(int count);

        bool operator==(const bookType &other);
        bool operator!=(const bookType &other);
        bool operator<(const bookType &other);
        bool operator<=(const bookType &other);
        bool operator>=(const bookType &other);
        bool operator>(const bookType &other);
        void operator=(const bookType &other);

    private:
        string bookTitle;
        string bookAuthor;
        string bookPublisher;
        string dateAdded;
        string bookISBN;
        int qtyOnHand;
        double bookWholesale;
        double bookRetail;
        static int bookCount;
};
```

Overloading code

```
bool bookType::operator==(const bookType &other){
    if (getQty() == other.getQty()) return true;
    else return false;
}

bool bookType::operator!=(const bookType &other){
    if (getQty() != other.getQty()) return true;
    else return false;
}

bool bookType::operator<(const bookType &other){
    if (getQty() < other.getQty()) return true;
    else return false;
}

bool bookType::operator<=(const bookType &other){
    if (getQty() <= other.getQty()) return true;
    else return false;
}

bool bookType::operator>=(const bookType &other){
    if (getQty() >= other.getQty()) return true;
    else return false;
}

bool bookType::operator>(const bookType &other){
    if (getQty() > other.getQty()) return true;
    else return false;
}

void bookType::operator=(const bookType &other){
    setTitle(other.getTitle());
    setAuthor(other.getAuthor());
    setPublisher(other.getPublisher());
    setDateAdded(other.getDateAdded());
    setISBN(other.getISBN());
    setQty(other.getQty());
    setWholesale(other.getWholesale());
    setRetail(other.getRetail());
}
```

Comment: Your selection sort is comparing pointer values, not the values of `bookType`s. You need to dereference the pointers to get the `bookType` values.

Comment: @CxsualtyGamin Off topic. but all you need is to overload `<` and `==`, and all the other operators can be derived from just those two operators.  It cuts down on mistakes and bugs that can occur.  They also should be `const` functions.

Comment: @CxsualtyGamin [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af4d6ffaba048835).  If `==` and/or `<` were more complex, you'll appreciate doing things this way, instead of trying to figure out the logic for all the other operators.